# How to Create a Vcl-Theme-Style for my own Component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, vcl-styles

I use the `BitmapStyleDesigner.exe` (shipped with delphi xe5) to edit vcl styles to my application.

How can i add a custom component to the styler palette? i want my `TMyButton`, which inherits `TButton`, have a different color, shape, etc than the standard `TButton`.

Can this be done only by editing the style, or do i have to edit the source of `TMyButton`?

The [embarcadero wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Working_with_VCL_Styles) hadn't helped (so far).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [`Objects with Text Info Buttons`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Bitmap_Style_Designer#Objects_with_Text_Info_Buttons) chapter.

Comment: ok, but how do i "connect" the `StyleObject` to a Component like TMyButton?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editing the VCL Style file is not enough. Unfortunately the VCL Styles are not designed to be extensible on the manner which your describe, Even if is technical possible do that, what you describe will require a lot of work. because you must modify the source of the `Vcl.Themes` and the `Vcl.Styles` units. My recommendation is not modify the style file, instead create a new style hook for your button and implement the paint code your self loading the images from a resource file.

Comment: thanks, that is the information i was looking for. now i have to learn about stylehooks :) (ps: i an old project we have a modified vcl, i would never modify it in a new app, this was one of the badest ideas my predecessor had)